# Deploying Python web app (Flask) in IIS using FastCGI get 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: python, iis, flask, fastcgi

I am trying to deploy Flask app in IIS.

But I get the 500 FastCGI error.

error code:"0x8007010b"

Here are the steps I've taken:

OS:windows10

Python version:3.6.5

1.install url rewrite2.0

2.pip install wfastcgi

3.Enable wfastcgi

4.create HelloAPI.py

5.create web.config

HelloAPI.py

```
from flask import Flask
app=Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/',methods=['GET'])
def index():
    return "Hello Flask!"

if __name__=='__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="FlaskFastCGI" path="*" verb="*" modules="FastCgiModule" scriptProcessor="d:\users\hhhung1\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\python.exe|d:\users\hhhung1\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\wfastcgi.py" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" />
    </handlers>
    <security> 
        <requestFiltering allowDoubleEscaping="true"></requestFiltering> 
    </security> 
  </system.webServer>

  <appSettings>
    <!-- Required settings -->
    <add key="WSGI_HANDLER" value="HelloAPI.app" />
    <add key="PYTHONPATH" value="~/" />
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Is there something I miss?

Comment: Look in the webserver error log.

Comment: Where is the error log ?

Comment: Problem solved. I grant the r/w right to python.exe folder and it works fine now.

Comment: If you found the solution, post it as an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved. I grant the r/w right to python.exe folder and it works fine now.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have read and execute permissions on the whole python folder that has python.exe for "IIS AppPool\DefaultAppPool"

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem granting r/w right to both folders:

- python.exe folder
- project folder

The two users I gave access to were the following:

- IIS_IUSRS
- IUSR